# Get a stacked-element box-shadow effect using only css?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a ui element which is supposed to indicate that the represented item will expand into multiple items later in the workflow. My thought is to have it look something like this:

[image: expending ui element]

Where the actual image is always different.

If the element is of this type it gets tagged with a special class `expandable-slide` This is an alpha version of the application so I don't care to spend very much time putting in new html and widgets, but it is also a Sunday so I'm willing to play around a bit and see if it is possible to get that effect using only css.

It occurs to me that the stacking effect is very similar to a `box-shadow`, just one that has multiple shadows with slightly different colors and offset by different amounts. I'm not sure that approach will work but that's what I'm currently trying.

Browser requirements are modern chrome/firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-shadow` can accept [multiple shadow effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/box-shadow) to emulate the look you're after.

```
.expandable-slide {
    margin: 2em 0 0 2em;
    box-shadow: -1em -1em #666,
                -2em -2em #333;
}
```

Working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/thefrontender/LwW7g/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I get for reading the docs from w3schools - incomplete documentation :)

Comment: MDN is a much better resource ... and usually just prefixing your web searches with "mdn " will return the right documentation. Hopefully the new Web Platform Docs will become more complete soon as well. Anything to rid the world of w3schools